# How to get "round_z" in asm code by HLSL?

Tags: assembly, shader, hlsl

When I'm reading the asm code ,I dont know how to get the instruction "round_" just below. Which function should I use in HLSL to get it? Or had it be replaced with the update of versions? The following is asm code:`round_z r15.x`

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be one, you can easily implement it though:

```
dst = sign(src) * floor(abs(src))
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is `modf`.
In the following snippet, `i` is the result of `round_z`:

```
float i;
modf(input, i);
```